# How to fill nan values based on two other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's say you have the following df:

```
     VAT       taxrate#1    taxrate#2    taxrate#3    taxrate#4    ExclVAT
--  -------  -----------  -----------  -----------  -----------  ---------
 0    19.95           21          nan          nan          nan      95
 2     0               0            0            0          nan     nan
 6     3.15          nan           21          nan          nan      15
 9   125.34           21          nan          nan          nan     596.86
11   540.69           21          nan          nan          nan    2574.73
13   254.31           21          nan          nan          nan    1211
15  1378.94          nan          nan          nan          nan    6566.36
18   401.65          nan          nan          nan          nan    1912.6
20    58.84          nan          nan          nan          nan     264.18
22    17.85           21          nan          nan          nan      85
24    16.38           21           21           21          nan      77.98
28   252              21           21          nan          nan    1200
31     6.24           21          nan          nan          nan      29.73
33    60.9            21           21          nan          nan     290
36    60.9            21           21          nan          nan     290
39    75.6            21           21          nan          nan     360
```

I need code that calculates the VAT amount if all taxrate values are NaN.

The VAT can be calculated and inserted in taxrate#1. VAT can be either 21%, 9% or 0%.

How to achieve this?

Desired output:

```
     VAT       taxrate#1    taxrate#2    taxrate#3    taxrate#4    ExclVAT
--  -------  -----------  -----------  -----------  -----------  ---------
 0    19.95           21          nan          nan          nan      95
 2     0               0            0            0          nan     nan
 6     3.15          nan           21          nan          nan      15
 9   125.34           21          nan          nan          nan     596.86
11   540.69           21          nan          nan          nan    2574.73
13   254.31           21          nan          nan          nan    1211
15  1378.94           21          nan          nan          nan    6566.36
18   401.65           21          nan          nan          nan    1912.6
20    58.84          nan          nan          nan          nan     264.18
22    17.85           21          nan          nan          nan      85
24    16.38           21           21           21          nan      77.98
28   252              21           21          nan          nan    1200
31     6.24           21          nan          nan          nan      29.73
33    60.9            21           21          nan          nan     290
36    60.9            21           21          nan          nan     290
39    75.6            21           21          nan          nan     360
```

I've tried the following code:

```
cols_to_check = ['taxrate#1', 'taxrate#2','taxrate#3']
dftaxitems['is_na'] = dftaxitems[cols_to_check].isnull().apply(lambda x: all(x), axis=1) 
dftaxitems

for i, row in dftaxitems.iterrows():
    if dftaxitems['is_na'][i] == True:
        dftaxitems['taxrate#1'] = dftaxitems['taxrate#1'].fillna((dftaxitems['BTW'].astype(float) / dftaxitems['ExclBTW'].astype(float)) * 100)
        
def custom_round(x, base=3):
    return int(base * round(float(x)/base))
dftaxitems['taxrate#1'] = dftaxitems['taxrate#1'].apply(lambda x: custom_round(x, base=3))
dftaxitems
```

However, this will lead to not rounding to 21, 9 or 0 or else np.nan.

I want the calculated amount to be exactly 21,9 or 0 and else a np.nan.

Now the code will round to the nearest table of 3 w/o looking at how close the value is to 21,9 or 0.

My question is:
How to assign 21%, 9% or 0% to taxrate#1 when dividing VAT by ExclVAT to calculate the VAT % and add it to taxrate #1.

Sorry if this is all a bit un-cohesive, I've worked for too long.
Please help!

Comment: can you explain more? why some rows of the ```textrate#1``` changed, when some others not?

Comment: Why is line 20 different than 22?

Comment: Yes Will do. The difference between 20 and 22 is that 58.84 / 264.18 = 0.22 and 17.85 / 85 = 0.21. I want the values to be exactly 0.21

Comment: @Max, does this mean you want to update VAT with correct value or ExclVAT with correct value and plug in 21 in the taxrate#1? More clarity on what you want to get done will be helpful. This is for row #20 with the ~22% vat

Comment: The simplest way to do this (with lots of assumptions is) `df['taxrate#1'] = df.apply(lambda x: round((x['VAT'] / x['ExclVAT']),2)*100 if pd.isnull(x['taxrate#1']) else x['taxrate#1'], axis=1).astype(int)`. Note here that row 20 gets 22 instead of 21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my assumptions for this work efforts.

1. Only update values in `taxrate#1` if `taxrate#1` is NULL.
2. All values in `ExclVAT` and `VAT` will have values. If the value is either `NaN` or 0, then the condition has to be expanded to check for them.
3. `VAT/ExclVAT` will provide the % for `taxrate#1`. No additional computational adjustments need to be done.

If we agree with these assumptions, then you can achieve this using:

```
df['taxrate#1'] = df.apply(lambda x: round((x['VAT'] / x['ExclVAT']),2)*100 if pd.isnull(x['taxrate#1']) else x['taxrate#1'], axis=1).astype(int)
```

Once I have more clarity on the approach and if you are expecting VAT value or ExclVAT value to be modified, then the code can be changed to address it.

The output of this will be (PS: I kept the ID column for reference):

```
    id      VAT  taxrate#1  taxrate#2  taxrate#3  taxrate#4  ExclVAT
0    0    19.95         21        NaN        NaN        NaN    95.00
1    2     0.00          0        0.0        0.0        NaN      NaN
2    6     3.15         21       21.0        NaN        NaN    15.00
3    9   125.34         21        NaN        NaN        NaN   596.86
4   11   540.69         21        NaN        NaN        NaN  2574.73
5   13   254.31         21        NaN        NaN        NaN  1211.00
6   15  1378.94         21        NaN        NaN        NaN  6566.36
7   18   401.65         21        NaN        NaN        NaN  1912.60
8   20    58.84         22        NaN        NaN        NaN   264.18
9   22    17.85         21        NaN        NaN        NaN    85.00
10  24    16.38         21       21.0       21.0        NaN    77.98
11  28   252.00         21       21.0        NaN        NaN  1200.00
12  31     6.24         21        NaN        NaN        NaN    29.73
13  33    60.90         21       21.0        NaN        NaN   290.00
14  36    60.90         21       21.0        NaN        NaN   290.00
15  39    75.60         21       21.0        NaN        NaN   360.00
```

If you want to force a VAT rate, you can decide to do the following:

```
df['taxrate#Y'] = df.apply(lambda x: round((x['VAT'] / x['ExclVAT']),2)*100 if not (pd.isnull(x['ExclVAT']) or pd.isnull(x['VAT'])) else 0, axis=1).astype(int)

df.loc[df['taxrate#Y'] > 15, 'taxrate#Y'] = 21
df.loc[(df['taxrate#Y'] > 0) & (df['taxrate#Y'] <= 15), 'taxrate#Y'] = 9
```

This is in comparison with the earlier solution I posted. I have created a new column `taxrate#X`. The code is the same but I am assigning it to new column instead of writing it back to `taxrate#1`.

```
df['taxrate#X'] = df.apply(lambda x: round((x['VAT'] / x['ExclVAT']),2)*100 if pd.isnull(x['taxrate#1']) else x['taxrate#1'], axis=1).astype(int)
```

The output of this will be:

```
    id      VAT  taxrate#1  taxrate#2  ...  taxrate#4  ExclVAT  taxrate#X  taxrate#Y
0    0    19.95       21.0        NaN  ...        NaN    95.00         21         21
1    2     0.00        0.0        0.0  ...        NaN      NaN          0          0
2    6     3.15        NaN       21.0  ...        NaN    15.00         21         21
3    9   125.34       21.0        NaN  ...        NaN   596.86         21         21
4   11   540.69       21.0        NaN  ...        NaN  2574.73         21         21
5   13   254.31       21.0        NaN  ...        NaN  1211.00         21         21
6   15  1378.94        NaN        NaN  ...        NaN  6566.36         21         21
7   18   401.65        NaN        NaN  ...        NaN  1912.60         21         21
8   20    58.84        NaN        NaN  ...        NaN   264.18         22         21
9   22    17.85       21.0        NaN  ...        NaN    85.00         21         21
10  24    16.38       21.0       21.0  ...        NaN    77.98         21         21
11  28   252.00       21.0       21.0  ...        NaN  1200.00         21         21
12  31     6.24       21.0        NaN  ...        NaN    29.73         21         21
13  33    60.90       21.0       21.0  ...        NaN   290.00         21         21
14  36    60.90       21.0       21.0  ...        NaN   290.00         21         21
15  39    75.60       21.0       21.0  ...        NaN   360.00         21         21
```

Note here that I have NOT modified the `VAT` or `ExclVAT` values based on the `taxrate#Y` value. If needed, we can do a compute and adjust the dollars accordingly. Again, need more clarity on which one needs to be adjusted. `VAT` or `ExclVAT`.